# Possible solutions to generate a bearer token with username/password to access an API endpoint

Tags: azure, api

There's a Microsoft product which authenticate me via my Azure AD login and when I click on a button, it calls an API and shows the result.

I now want to access the same API programmatically... is it even possible?

Upon inspecting the network tab on chrome for the API call, I could able to replicate in POSTMAN and it worked. It was simple as it calls the endpoint and pass the bearer token in authorization header. I copied the bearer token from chrome network tab and it worked.

Only thing I am struggling to figure out is how to generate the bearer token with my username/password.

I read some articles and it says to register the app in Azure portal. Is it really required? Please give me idea

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged this firebase-authentication, but that product doesn't seem to be involved at all in the question, so I'm removing it.

Comment: my apologies. I didn't add that one. Perhaps a mistake